# Sometimes Chrome Web Driver is not loading link using Selenium Python

Tags: multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

hope you all are fine.
I'm opening a link using this code,

```
def load_url():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)

def scrap_matches(urls):
    for url in urls:
        load_url(url)
```

Use Case:
I'm using a list of urls and passing them one by one to "load_url" function.

I'm using multithreading i.e. There are 4 threads and each thread is working on a list of urls like this,

```
# part_1 and part_2 are the lists.
t1 = threading.Thread(target=scrap_matches, args=(part_1,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=scrap_matches, args=(part_2,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Sometimes an empty chrome tab opens without loading any content of page. Link is present in link portion of chrome. When I refreshes that tab manually then website loads successfully.
I need to avoid this situation. I have searched about it but could not find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: Timeout error after 300 seconds

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000

Comment: There's a `driver.refresh` command that might be bandage to get you moving - but it's not a good solution.  Is it repeatable? - Does it always fail at the same point? Or is it always at a different point in the script or different url?   - i assume as well your machine is capable of running 4 concurrent threads?

Comment: Yes it's repeatable but it does not fail at the same point.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new webdriver for every url... only 1 for each thread.